# Flagged email count different on iPhone and Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, mail.app

In Mail app on iPhone 12 running iOS 16.3.1, the number of emails marked as flagged is 48 when on MacBook Pro M1 running macOS Ventura 13.2.1, it is 38. There is the right number of flagged emails on MacBook. Why is there a difference between my two devices? I have installed the newest update on both devices and deleted Envelope files on MacBook and reindexed.

Comment: Are the 10 emails (the difference between 48 and 38) available/visible on the MacBook? What happens if you flag one of them on the Mac, and unflag it again 15 minutes later? What happens if you flag a currently unflagged mail on the Mac, and unflag it again 15 minutes later?